# Android image intent : sharing/editing options

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I'm trying to launch an intent for viewing an image from storage, but once the gallery viewer opened, it appears with **sharing** and **editing** options.
Is there any extra or flag to tell the intent to disable those properties.
All i want is the plain image viewer (the video player for example doesn't show sharing options by default)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no such intent, nor flag. If you want just plain viewer use `ImageView`:

```
  ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
  File f = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
  iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(f.toString()));
```