# Android intent ACTION_VIEW with share options

Tags: android, android-intent, photo-gallery

I'm using an intent with ACTION_VIEW to view a photo on android, but it doesnt open with any of the options the gallery has when viewing other pictures (specifically share). Anyone know how to make it have those options?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(location, mimeType);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

gives me a viewer like this:
[image]

but just viewing in the gallery, i get all this stuff:
[image]

these issues are similar, but had no answer

[Intent Action_View for image opens gallery with no delete option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735344/intent-action-view-for-image-opens-gallery-with-no-delete-option)

[Android image intent : sharing/editing options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957571/android-image-intent-sharing-editing-options)

and the interesting thing is both of those issues talk about those options ALREADY being available... so im not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it doesnt open with any of the options the gallery has when viewing other pictures (specifically share)

There are ~2 billion Android devices, made up of thousands of device models. Many of those device models will ship with 1+ activities that support your `Intent` structure, and many of the actual devices will have other apps that support it, installed by users. None have to offer a "share" option.

> Anyone know how to make it have those options?

Strictly speaking, you can't.

Those image-viewing apps were written by developers, and those developers can do whatever they want. Perhaps there are different activities for internal use vs. `ACTION_VIEW`. Perhaps it is the same activity, but they only offer those options when the activity is reached internally (vs. from outside apps via `ACTION_VIEW`). Perhaps they only share certain `Uri` schemes or MIME types. Perhaps they do not share images because it is Tuesday.

And, again, the behavior will be different on different devices, based on which image-viewing apps the user has and chooses to use.

If you want to have a "share" option, *put it in your app*. If you want that share option to be on the screen that shows the image, *show the image in your app*. Right now, you are delegating all of that to third-party apps, and those apps do not have to do what you want.

Comment: yeah, i was pretty sure this was the answer. i thought maybe there was a flag or something i was missing that i should send with the intent. or send the intent with both actions or i donno... anyway, just wanted to check. thanks for the prompt response! always helpful

Comment: @Josh: "i thought maybe there was a flag or something" -- none that are part of the Android SDK. It is entirely possible that some image-viewing apps offer extras that control this, but that would be up to those apps, and I am not aware of any standards in this area.